# INR not supported in paypal magento

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I am developing an online shopping site, which sells products using Indian Rupees (INR). When I link this to PayPal with Indian Rupees as the base currency, it redirects back to the shopping cart without taking me to PayPal.

When I use a currency converter and change the value to USD, it shows the error "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)". Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Magento does not support INR As base currency

Comment: Since I have few International customers, Is there any other way or extension that can perform it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a payed module is the best answer, but it sure was worth the 29 dollars for me:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-multi-currency.html

Answer (score 0):

I add INR currency on PayPal supported currency codes And it's working.